# Timer stops working after sometime in windows service

Tags: vb.net, system.timers.timer

I have a windows service that runs every one minute and performs some DB and IO operations.

Everything works fine but I have observed that after some time service does not work.

It shows started but nothing is happening.

1) Can this be bcoz of timer being collected by GC? If yes then whats wrong with my code.

2) I have used timer.enable in onstart and onstop, should i use timer.start and timer.stop.

3) If I want to user Threading.Timer then what all do I need to change in the following code.

Any help will be appreciated

```
Imports System.ServiceProcess
Imports System.Timers
Imports System.Configuration

Public Class ReportingImmediate
    Inherits ServiceBase

#Region "Members"

    Private ReadOnly time As Timers.Timer
    Private ReadOnly ReportingHelper As ReportingHelper
    Private ReadOnly timeInterval As String

#End Region

    Public Sub New()
        ' Initialize Logs
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Initialize other components
        time = New System.Timers.Timer()
        timeInterval = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ImmediateReRunInterval")
        time.Interval = Integer.Parse(timeInterval)
        AddHandler time.Elapsed, AddressOf TimeElapsed
        objReportingHelper = New ReportingHelper()

    End Sub

#Region "Timer Event"

    ''' <summary>time Elapsed</summary>
    ''' <param name="sender">The object that raised the event sender</param>
    ''' <param name="e">Event data passed to the handler e</param>
    Private Sub TimeElapsed(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
        time.Enabled = False
        objReportingHelper.GetReportsForExecutions(1)
        ' Enable the Timer
        time.Enabled = True
        time.Interval = Integer.Parse(timeInterval)
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Service Events"

    ''' <summary>On Start</summary>
    ''' <param name="args">Arguments</param>
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(args As String())
        time.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>On Stop</summary>
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        time.Enabled = False
    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

Comment: Is `objReportingHelper.GetReportsForExecutions(1)` throwing an exception?  Wrap it in a `try`/`finally`.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use a service? Why not just a scheduled task that runs every minute? see: http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway//428303

Comment: @basher, no specific reason to use service. Just that I thought service will be more suitable as it needs to execute every one minute.

Comment: @Mitch, I have wrapped it in a try/catch/finally block and no exception has been logged so far. I will keep on checking but do you think of any other reason why it will stop working. What about time being collected by GC?

Comment: I see nothing which would prevent the timer from firing.  It is not a GC issue, the timer would be a root since you are using `System.Timers.Timer`.  Even if you were using `System.Threading.Timer`, you are keeping a reference to it.

Comment: @NikhilGupta I'd seriously just switch to a scheduled task. It's perfectly suited for what you're looking to accomplish. You can just delete all the timer code in your source and just focus on the functionality. Leverage the Task Scheduler as your timer.

Comment: @basher, why do u think windows service is not a suitable choice. I have also read the article mentioned by u. My service runs every one minute and check the DB for newly scheduled reports and then start processing them. Do u think scheduling a task that runs every one minute will be better utilization of resources and what about the hardware failure. Windows service can restart automatically.

Comment: A service is recommended when the App must stay alive to accomplish it's task (ie continuosly watch a a log or file for changes or waiting for windows event trigger).  A scheduled task is better for when you only need the program to run periodically (Ie. checking a file every minute, backing up a database every night").  The downside to tasks is that deploying them to multiple devices / troubleshooting can be more difficult.  That being said, I don't think that a service is "Wrong" here, but the question is: "Is it worth your time to fix?"

Comment: As @Mitch eluded to, unhandled exceptions get hidden within timer events, but will stop the timer.  If you threw everything in the timer event into a try/catch, I suspect you wont see the timer stop.  Just make sure that  your timer is still enabled in the finally block, in case the exception is thrown after it is disabled.